# Handle User update Validation in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

When calling update_user() on my Model_Auth_User inside a try catch block, but I'm getting a multidimensional array on my $e->errors('validation') call with the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [_external] => Array
        (
            [password] => Array
                (
                    [0] => min_length
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => asdf
                            [1] => 8
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Where I usually get an array starting without the `_external` wrapper. Anybody know what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Kohana can't find the messages in the 'validation' file you specified, so it's returning the messages as "file/field/rule".

Have a look here:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Validation#errors

In particular, these conditionals:

```php
if ($message = Kohana::message($file, "{$field}.{$error}"))
{
    // Found a message for this field and error
}
elseif ($message = Kohana::message($file, "{$field}.default"))
{
    // Found a default message for this field
}
elseif ($message = Kohana::message($file, $error))
{
    // Found a default message for this error
}
elseif ($message = Kohana::message('validation', $error))
{
    // Found a default message for this error
}
else
{
    // No message exists, display the path expected
    $message = "{$file}.{$field}.{$error}";
}
```

Also, I think you need to store the messages file in the following location: ./application/messages/validation/_external.php

Comment: Not exactly was I was looking for, but this helps. I just thought it was some kind of error receiving the _external array.